# How to pass Category value from test to TearDown

Tags: c#, nunit, teardown

I am running a test with the following attributes
[TestCase(“First Count”), Category(“Catalog”)]

Later in TearDown I want to get the value "Catalog". I tried:

> var cat = (string)TestContext.CurrentContext.Test.Properties.Get("Category");

But as a result - null
I also tried to add [Property("value","Catalog")] to the test attributes
Still the same result. How else can you do it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With the syntax you are using, the Category is not applied to the individual test case but to the method as a whole, that is to the (internal) test suite created by NUnit to hold **all** the test cases for that method.

To apply a Category to a **single** test case, use this syntax: [TestCase("FirstCount", Category="Catalog")]

That said... there could be other problems since you haven't shown the entire TearDown method. If the above doesn't fix it, pelase edit your question to include the full method.